# Code throwing unhandled rejection error when running promise

Tags: javascript, async-await, try-catch, es6-promise

**I am trying to write a Javascript promise that resolves and rejects the desired variables. I am getting the error message below after running in the console**

```
[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().
 code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'
```

*Here is my code*

**Js File:**

```
const grimeUserLeft = false;
const userWatchingGrimeVids = true;

let grimePromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  if (grimeUserLeft) {
    reject("User Left");
  } else if (userWatchingGrimeVids) {
    reject("This user is a G");
  } else {
    resolve("Congrats. Your channel doesn't suck");
  }
});

grimePromise.then((message) => {
  console.log("Success: " + message);
});
grimePromise.catch((message) => {
  console.log("You Failed: " + message);
});
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "*a promise that resolves and rejects the desired variable*". That's not what promises do. Since your code is not doing anything asynchronous, you should not use promises here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By calling the `.then()` and the `.catch()` handler on two different places, you actually end up with two different promises - each of `.then()` and `.catch()` returns a new one. The promise returned by `.then()` will *not* be caught by the separate `.catch()` handler:

```js
const grimeUserLeft = false;
const userWatchingGrimeVids = true;

let grimePromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  if (grimeUserLeft) {
    reject("User Left");
  } else if (userWatchingGrimeVids) {
    reject("This user is a G");
  } else {
    resolve("Congrats. Your channel doesn't suck");
  }
});

grimePromise
  .then((message) => {
    console.log("Success: " + message);
  })
  .catch(() => console.log(1));

grimePromise.catch((message) => {
  console.log(2);
  console.log("You Failed: " + message);
});
```

Therefore, one promise gets turned into two. Each of them will adopt the state of the original promise. When the original is rejected, both the derived promises reject. Yet only one is handled.

Instead, you can directly specify the `.catch()` in the same promise chain as the `.then()`:

```js
const grimeUserLeft = false;
const userWatchingGrimeVids = true;

let grimePromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  if (grimeUserLeft) {
    reject("User Left");
  } else if (userWatchingGrimeVids) {
    reject("This user is a G");
  } else {
    resolve("Congrats. Your channel doesn't suck");
  }
});

grimePromise
  .then((message) => {
    console.log("Success: " + message);
  })
  .catch((message) => {
    console.log("You Failed: " + message);
  });
```

```html
<h1>Check the browser console - no unhandled promise rejections</h1>
```

Or alternatively, specify both handlers in the `then()`:

```js
const grimeUserLeft = false;
const userWatchingGrimeVids = true;

let grimePromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  if (grimeUserLeft) {
    reject("User Left");
  } else if (userWatchingGrimeVids) {
    reject("This user is a G");
  } else {
    resolve("Congrats. Your channel doesn't suck");
  }
});

grimePromise
  .then(
    (message) => {
      console.log("Success: " + message);
    },
    (message) => {
      console.log("You Failed: " + message);
    }
  );
```

```html
<h1>Check the browser console - no unhandled promise rejections</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason this isn't working is because you didn't have a .catch() on the first one. It was throwing a rejection, but you weren't handling it gracefully with a catch, so it threw.

Here is your code working - I just moved your catch block to go after the .then:

```js
const grimeUserLeft = false;
const userWatchingGrimeVids = true;

const grimePromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (grimeUserLeft) {
        reject('User Left');
    } else if (userWatchingGrimeVids) {
        reject('This user is a G');
    } else {
        resolve("Congrats. Your channel doesn't suck");
    }
});

grimePromise
    .then((message) => {
        console.log('Success: ' + message);
    })
    .catch((message) => {
        console.log('You Failed: ' + message);
    });
```

Just as a tip though, you should only reject whenever the function is unsuccessful in some way. That could be a timeout, a network error, incorrect input etc. Whatever is inside of a reject should ideally be an error.

Additionally, I'd recommend using async await, as it's much easier to read and more manageable. You can easily do this by creating a function which returns your new Promise, then awaiting it like so:

```js
const grimeUserLeft = false;
const userWatchingGrimeVids = true;

const grime = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (grimeUserLeft) {
            reject(new Error('User Left'));
        } else if (userWatchingGrimeVids) {
            resolve('This user is a G');
        } else {
            resolve("Congrats. Your channel doesn't suck");
        }
    });
};

const doStuff = async () => {
    try {
        const result = await grime();
        console.log(result);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
};

doStuff();
```

To make this truly asynchronous, you should ideally be doing some async stuff inside of the promise. This can be demonstrated with a setTimeout:

```js
const grimeUserLeft = false;
const userWatchingGrimeVids = true;

const grime = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (grimeUserLeft) {
                reject(new Error('User Left'));
            } else if (userWatchingGrimeVids) {
                resolve('This user is a G');
            } else {
                resolve("Congrats. Your channel doesn't suck");
            }
        }, 2000);
    });
};

const doStuff = async () => {
    try {
        const result = await grime();
        console.log('result finished after 2 seconds');

        console.log(result);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
};

doStuff();
```